# ffmpeg, mpg, mp4, dv-rms and wtv

Tags: ffmpeg

my query has been bugging me for several years.

I use Windows MCE to record TV and Watch movies through Networked PC's. On the odd occasion I miss an episode and manage to download it in mpg or mp4 format I can't find any programme that will convert this to WTV or DV-rms format.

From my understanding the Video and audio streams are essentially mpg even when in dvrms or wtv format?

Is there a way I can convert these please?

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Can you show the complete output of: `ffmpeg -i typical_video_that_works_on_mce.wtv`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i'd suggest is try renaming the file to .wtv and see where you get.

Failing that, then see what Mediainfo brings up on the container and the codecs https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo and using something like Handbrake to re-encode the video into a similar format.

If i'd hazard a guess and knowing microsoft WTV is probably a WMV container with the original MPEG 2 Video stream and MPEG layer 2 Audio. but that's just a complete guess.

Comment: Thanks, but you or I might have got things wrong the originals downloaded are mp4 or mpg and I want them in to wtv or dv-rms.